# How I can hide table column's based on multi-select (values)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using Angular, I have a table with 3 columns, 2 of them are static and one is a dynamic (I mean I am using `ng-repeat`), actually this column (number 3) like a column for a months (April, June, etc), all I need is to show a multi select field in the html.

When I select June + April + May, the table should be updated but also I need the values on the multi select field to be dynamic (according to the columns).

This is my code

```
<table class="table" dir="rtl"> <thead> </thead> <tbody> <tr> <td class="tg-col">element</td> <td id="test" class="tg-col" ng-repeat="arrayItem in data.information" class="tg-col">{{::arrayItem.month}}    </td> <td class="tg-col">total</td> </tr>
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to achieve. Do you want to have a set of checkboxes based on items in the `data.information`? Do you want to show in the multi-select control only items, which are checked in the data.information`?

Comment: I need to update a field column " TOTAL BASIC ", this colums should display a total of all rows, but I have a filter for a month(multi select), so when I click on june, the total should be only for june, when i unselect june, the total should be 0, the problem that when i unselect june, the total stay for june

Comment: It would be helpful to see more (properly formatted) code, because there is nothing related to checkboxes or totals calculation in provided example.